# PDE solving using change of variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have to solve these PDE **using change of variables.**
1)$p(x) $$\partial f \over \partial x $$+q(y) $$\partial   f \over \partial y $=0
A hint is given as to use $u=\int {1\over p}dx$, $v=\int {1\over q}dy$

2)$f_x+f_{yx}=0$
I did the problem $f_x+f_{xy}=0$ with the substitution $u=f_x $.Then the equation simplifies to $U+U_y=0$
$\int {1 \over u}du$=$\int -dy$

But the problem is in $f_x+f_{yx}=0$ if I take $u=f_x $ I have a problem substituting for $f_{yx}$ part.
Any help on how I can do these problems please

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If you let $u = f_x$, then we have ( since $f_{xy} = f_{yx} = \partial_y ( f_x)$ )

$$ f_x + f_{xy} =0 \iff u + u_y = 0 \iff -\int dy = \int \frac{du}{u}  \iff u = C(x)\exp(-y)$$

Then all you have to solve is

$$ f_x = C(x) \exp(-y)  $$

Where $C(x)$ is any function that depends on $x$. If you have some conditions on the function, you can then get an explicit form.

Edit: Otherwise all you have is

$$f(x,y) = \exp(-y) \int C(x) dx = F(x) \exp(-y) $$

where $F(x)$ is any function $F:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that is differentiable

Also, for your first question consider this:

$$ p(x) f_x + q(y) f_y = 0 \iff \frac{p(x)f_x}{f_y} = - q(y)  $$

What does this tell us? This should lead you to the conclusion that $f = u-v$ where $u$ and $v$ are as you defined.

Comment: I also come up to the part $f_x = C(x) \exp(-y)$.But that is assuming $f_{xy} = f_{yx} = \partial_y ( f_x)$.The problem is I'v been given two problems as $f_x+f_{yx}=0$ and $f_x+f_{xy}=0$ which under the assumption of $f_{yx}=f_{xy}$ be the same problem.Is there  a way I can do this without the assumption $f_{yx}=f_{xy}$.Also I am stuck with integrating  $C(x) \exp(-y)$ .What should be done to C(x) when integrating with respect to x

Comment: You can prove $f_{xy} = f_{yx}$, it's not just an assumption here. Also, $f_{yx} = \partial_y \partial_x f$ is just a notation thing.

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit as to how $\frac{p(x)f_x}{f_y} = - q(y)$ leads to $f = u-v$

Comment: what I get is $f_x=f_u.u_x$ and  $f_y=f_v.v_y$.Since $U_x={1 \over p(x)}$ and $v_y={1 \over q(y)}$ I get $f_u+f_v=0$.Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is another way to get the same conclusion.

Comment: :Can you please explain your method a little bit